# Condense multiple nested select statements

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I am trying to get the latest vote (based on dateCreated) for each userId. My attempt below works, but I feel like multiple nested SELECT statements is incredibly inefficient. Anyone have a better solution? Im fairly new to SQL so I would appreciate a walk through of your solution as well as the code.

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT t.userId 
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT userId,vote,dateCreated 
        FROM pgVote 
        WHERE categoryId = 528 
        ORDER BY dateCreated DESC
    ) 
    AS t
) 
AS u
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT aa.*
FROM pgVote aa
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT userId, MAX(dateCreated) as latestDate
    FROM pgVote
    WHERE categoryId = 528
    GROUP BY userId
) bb ON aa.userId = bb.userId AND aa.dateCreated = bb.latestDate
```

Table bb is just a list of userid with the latest date. Once you inner join with aa which is the full table, then it will filter the latest vote for you.